# Tracing an ignored exception in Python?

Tags: python, exception

My app has a custom audio library that itself uses the BASS library.

I create and destroy BASS stream objects throughout the program.

When my program exits, randomly (I haven't figured out the pattern yet) I get the following notice on my console:

```
Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <bound method stream.__del__ of <audio.audio_player.stream object at 0xaeda2f0>> ignored
```

My audio library (audio/audio_player.py [class Stream]) contains a class that creates a BASS stream object and then allows the code to manipulate it. When the class is destroyed (in the **del** routine) it calls BASS_StreamFree to clear any resources BASS might have allocated.

(audio_player.py)

```
from pybass import *
from ctypes import pointer, c_float, c_long, c_ulong, c_buffer
import os.path, time, threading

# initialize the BASS engine
BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, None)

class stream(object):
    """Represents a single audio stream"""
    def __init__(self, file):
        # check for file existence
        if (os.path.isfile(file) == False):
            raise ValueError("File %s not found." % file)
        # initialize a bass channel
        self.cAddress = BASS_StreamCreateFile(False, file, 0, 0, 0)
    def __del__(self):
        BASS_StreamFree(self.cAddress)
    def play(self):
        BASS_ChannelPlay(self.cAddress, True)
        while (self.playing == False):
            pass
    ..more code..
```

My first inclination based on this message is that somewhere in my code, an instance of my stream class is being orphaned (no longer assigned to a variable) and Python still is trying to call its **del** function when the app closes, but by the time it tries the object has gone away.

This app does use wxWidgets and thus involves some threading. The fact that I'm not being given an actual variable name leads me to believe what I stated in the previous paragraph.

I'm not sure exactly what code would be relevant to debug this. The message does seem harmless but I don't like the idea of an "ignored" exception in the final production code.

Is there any tips anyone has for debugging this?

Comment: "wxWidgets" Uh oh, expect stuff to go away when you don't expect it unless you do more work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The message that the exception was ignored is because all exceptions raised in a `__del__` method are ignored to keep the data model sane. Here's the relevant portion of [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> **Warning:** Due to the precarious circumstances under which `__del__()` methods are invoked, exceptions that occur during their execution are ignored, and a warning is printed to sys.stderr instead. Also, when `__del__()` is invoked in response to a module being deleted (e.g., when execution of the program is done), other globals referenced by the `__del__()` method may already have been deleted or in the process of being torn down (e.g. the import machinery shutting down). For this reason, `__del__()` methods should do the absolute minimum needed to maintain external invariants. Starting with version 1.5, Python guarantees that globals whose name begins with a single underscore are deleted from their module before other globals are deleted; if no other references to such globals exist, this may help in assuring that imported modules are still available at the time when the `__del__()` method is called.

As for debugging it, you could start by putting a `try`/`except` block around the code in your `__del__` method and printing out more information about the program's state at the time it occurs. Or you could consider doing less in the `__del__` method, or getting rid of it entirely!

Comment: You were right. The exception was being caused in the `__del__` method. I just wrapped the call inside a try/catch and all seems good now.