# Python trace ignored exception on exit

Tags: python, exception, traceback

I am having a problem finding out how to capture and report a trace for an ignored exception in Python.  I have seen that python will ignore exceptions raised in the "`__del__`" method but I would actually like to find out where the error is coming from to fix it.

This is similar to issue; [Tracing an ignored exception in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620932/tracing-an-ignored-exception-in-python), however I am looking for a way to track the error.

A simplification of the code is;

```
import os, os.path, sys
import ...

print "Success"
```

And the output is;

```
Success
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'debug'" in  ignored
```

Thanks

Comment: Not a full solution, but `del` everything you've still got in globals at the end of your program. Maybe you'll get lucky.

Comment: Thanks, I changed some of the imports around and now am not getting the error, but the issue persists of how to get the stack trace of these ignored errors.  I would have thought that there was an option like use strict which would raise the exception even when in `__del__`.