# Enter Python debugger on an exception ignored by a library

Tags: python, pandas, debugging, exception, ipython

I have introduced a bug in some complicated code which is noisily swallowed by some library code I don't want to learn about:

```
In [212]: start = time() ; result = big_messy_thing() ; stop = time() ; print(stop-start)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.map_locations()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
Exception ignored in: 'pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._call_map_locations'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5231, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.map_locations
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.map_locations()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
Exception ignored in: 'pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._call_map_locations'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5231, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.map_locations
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
6.994357109069824
```

I would like to enter the debugger when this happens, so I can confirm that this apparent non-problem isn't causing problematic side effects.  Can I do this using standard-library tools?

I have found [this decade-old question about ignored exceptions in `__del__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16620932/1650379); if my problem is in any of *my* `__del__`, it's sneaky enough that I still need a debugger to find it.  I also see [a similar unanswered question from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25860479/1650379), and [an even-older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11966276/1650379) about doing this kind of thing in [the PyCharm IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). I would prefer not to try running this code from an IDE; I suspect that would introduce as many problems as it would solve, just because nothing ever works right the first time.

I seem to be running Python 3.8.3, IPython version 7.22.0, and Pandas version 1.3.0, installed via Anaconda on an up-to-date MacOS.

I have discovered the IPython magic function `%pdb on`, but in this case it doesn't appear to generate any stack trace for the ignored error: the PDB command `list` generates nothing, and `up` and `down` tell me I'm in both the oldest and the newest frame.

I've solved this particular problem by manually adding pairs of `breakpoint()` calls until I found the line of code, like a by-hand bisection search, but I sure would have preferred some debugger incantation to deposit me at the problem.

Comment: "Unhashable type: Series" suggests that you're using a `Series` as a dictionary key or something similar.  I assume that's somewhere in `big_messy_thing()`.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have a bunch of `@lru_cache` things happening to avoid double-computing things, and I suspect that an argument to one of them has accidentally been promoted to a Series. Except I would expect that to generate an un-swallowed exception, so I remain confused.

Comment: For what it's worth, my guess was wrong. I made the message go away by replacing a `dataFrame1.apply( lambda interval: dataFrame2.loc[ interval.left ] )` with a `dataFrame2.loc[ dataFrame1.apply( pd.Interval.left.__get__ ) ]`. I'm not sure why those are different; it could be a Pandas bug.