# Fitting NN model with tensorflow throws error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv#build_the_model) on implementing a simple neural network, that would read data from a csv file. Here is the data stored in `games.csv`

```
white_pawns, black_pawns, white_queens, black_queens,result
3, 4, 1, 1, -1
3, 5, 1, 2, -1
6, 4, 0, 0, 1
2, 2, 3, 1, 1
5, 2, 0, 3, -1
10, 10, 0, 0, 1
8, 10, 0, 1, -1
```

And here is the code created following the instructions. My columns are already numeric so I skipped that part of the tutorial.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def pack(features, label):
    return tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis=-1), label

labelColumn = 'result'
labels = [-1, 1]

train_file_path = "C:/games.csv"

games_train = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    train_file_path,
    batch_size=5,
    label_name=labelColumn,
    na_value="?",
    num_epochs=1,
    ignore_errors=True
)

packed_dataset = games_train.map(pack)
train_data = packed_dataset.shuffle(500)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(4,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_data, epochs=1)
```

It seems that the data is read correctly, but when trying to call `model.fit(train_data, epochs=1)` I get an error:

```
    2/Unknown - 2s 1s/step - loss: 1.0507 - accuracy: 0.0000e+002020-02-02 15:14:00.577149: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Out of range: End of sequence
         [[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]
2/2 [==============================] - 2s 1s/step - loss: 1.0507 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Exception ignored in: <function _RandomSeedGeneratorDeleter.__del__ at 0x000001FAF02041F8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 3009, in __del__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'device'
Exception ignored in: <function _RandomSeedGeneratorDeleter.__del__ at 0x000001FAF02041F8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 3009, in __del__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'device'
Exception ignored in: <function _RandomSeedGeneratorDeleter.__del__ at 0x000001FAF02041F8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 3009, in __del__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'device'
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Tensorflow are you using? Tf2.0 this might not be an issue.

It seems that it might be a bug in TF, to rectify, you can look at editing the tensorflow code in site-packages;

In **dataset_ops.py**, at the top of the file add

```py
import tensorflow as tf
```

and then on line 2944 and 3009 replace:

```
with ops.device(self._device):
```

with

```
with tf.device(self._device):
```

Refer to the bug report here;

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35326

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok. You can ensure yourself by making couple of blank lines after your code. You will see that code runs and finishes fine and errors are printed while program stops.

Problem is in TensorFlow.
As you can see each exception is caught and afterwards printed with information: `Exception ignored in:`. Your code is executed fine till the end. After that TF tries to delete it's objects and encounters some problems within. TF can handle them but prints them out just "because".

SPECULATION TIME:

I guess it's some mismatch between TF1 and eager execution in TF2. During deletion some inner "cleaning" function tries to access property `device` of already deleted  item. Therefor raises error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'device'`. This error is caught, ignored, printed for good measure and cleaning-up moves on.

Similar problem I encountered in work while using tensorflow-hub. Seems like there are some minor but irritating problems in current releases.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's actually nothing wrong here.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16620987/997378) quoting the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)

Mainly:

> **Warning:** Due to the precarious circumstances under which `__del__()` methods are invoked, exceptions that occur during their execution are ignored, and a warning is printed to sys.stderr instead. Also, when `__del__()` is invoked in response to a module being deleted (e.g., when execution of the program is done), other globals referenced by the `__del__()` method may already have been deleted or in the process of being torn down (e.g. the import machinery shutting down).

That's why these are printed during exit, and "Exception Ignored" is printed with it.

This doesn't interrupt a running program, right?