Python ctypes: How to raise exception when my "Material" class goes out of scope without freeing resources in C level?
I'm writting a Graphics Rendering API with a "Material" class containing resources allocated by calling a "create_material" function in my C DLL, which should be accompanied by a respective "destroy_material" call.
I want to raise an exception when the Material class gets destroyed/GC'ed without calling the destroy_material, and I can't quite find a reliable way to do that, especially considering unit testing.
I tried this (self.handle is a c_void_p):
def __del__(self):
    if self.handle.value:
        raise ResourceNotDeallocated("Destroying material that was never destroyed on C side")

But this is highly counter advised due to how __del__ and GC really works, and I couldn't test a with self.assertRaises(...), even after calling gc.collect() it won't raise.
I also tried weakref.finalize approach, but Material's bound methods result in an extra reference count that defeats the purpose.
def __init__(self):
    self._finalizer = weakref.finalize(self, self._on_finalize_material, self)

def _on_finalize_material(self):
    if self.handle.value:
        msg = f"Destroying material that was never destroyed on Remix side (Handle: {material.handle}, Albedo: {material.albedo_texture})"
        raise ResourceNotDeallocated(msg)


Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16620987/12763954

You could require the use of a context manager as described here.

Seems like a flaw in the design, why not simply destroy the pointer in the destructor (if not already destroyed)?

Good points you all. Sadly a context manager won't work as I might need to deal with 100s or 1000s of materials in a 3D scene (can't be opening that many with blocks). Also I want to hold the user responsible to dispose their data as the API is just a thin wrapper over a C++ engine.
On a second thought though, maybe destroying the Material automatically might be a good approach.
Still I can't unit test this approach though

@EmanuelKozerski Why couldn't you unit test it?  Mock the destroy_material function and increment a global variable would be one way, since you can't raise an exception in __del__.  Or use a class variable in Material to count instances of Material.  Increment on creation and decrement on destroy.
